# Javascript form validation error message for textarea screws form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, message, innerhtml

OK so I am doing a basic form validation script of my course with the little knowledge I have in JavaScript I am not looking for a much more complicated yet shorter way of performing my validation via using loops or something like that, I am awaiting a java book to arrived and will learn more later for now I am just doing a basic validation script.

I just want to know why when I try to display an error message for textarea suddenly the form starts resetting completely.

form 1 works
http://www.richie.id.au/TAFE/form/enquiry.html
form 2 does not work
http://www.richie.id.au/TAFE/form2/enquiry.html

the only difference between the two is this piece of code that causes error messages to disappear:

```
    //Message message action if true of false
    if(messageMessage==true){
        document.getElementByID('messageError').innerHTML='*Please enter a message*';
    }
    if(messageMessage==false){
        document.getElementByID('messageError').innerHTML='';
    }
```

It's identical to my other messages so I'm not sure why it causes the form error messages to display for only a second then disappear. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**document.getElementByID** should be:

```
document.getElementById('messageError')... //small d not capital D
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is resetting because of its submitting (in second case). You have a mistype in `http://www.richie.id.au/TAFE/form2/clientSideValidator.js`:

```
    if(messageMessage==true){
        document.getElementByID('messageError').innerHTML='*Please enter a message*';
    }
    if(messageMessage==false){
        document.getElementByID('messageError').innerHTML='';
    }
```

Replace to:

```
if(messageMessage==true){
    document.getElementById('messageError').innerHTML="*Please enter a message*";
}
if(messageMessage==false){
    document.getElementById('messageError').innerHTML='';
}
```